# SSL on an IIS server that has renders php AND asp?

Tags: php, iis, ssl, asp

I have a client who's running a windows and IIS server.  On it is a website under one domain name that renders pages in both php and asp.  SO you will have a page with the url http://mysite.com/hello.php that links to a page with the url http://mysite.com/hello.asp.  The php pages are managed by a joomla cms while the asp pages are managed by a proprietary web software.

Client has expressed interest in putting some of these php and asp pages behind an SSL. I wasn't sure if this would cause problems.  I'm use to setting up ssl on apache servers where the php and html were the only types of pages hosted on the website.  Setting up an SSL on IIS to encrypt some php and asp pages shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: There is no difference -- I'm running similar thing under IIS 6 and IIS 7.x and have (and never had) no issues with SSL in this regard. Yes, those files are in different folders (e.g. all *.asp in `/asparea/` and *.php are everywhere else), but that makes no difference.

Comment: thank you, can you post thisas answer?  Then i can acept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no difference** -- I'm running similar thing under both IIS 6 and IIS 7.x and have (and never had) no issues with SSL in this regard.

Yes, in my case those files are in different folders (e.g. all *.asp files are in `/asparea/` and *.php are everywhere else), but that still makes no difference.